# Autocomplete input jQuery (like Microsoft Excel functionality)

Tags: javascript

I need your help this time. I require to develop an autocompleter input in a web form. The suggestions must be from a previous calculated list. The autocompleter must be like Microsoft Excel functionality. For example, you have the following list: George Washington, George Harrison and George Boole. If you type "George", it must not show any suggestion. But if you type "George W", it must show the shaded text "ashington", so, if you press enter, the input will be filled with the phrase "George Washington". I have implemented some autocompleters in JavaScript, but this time I need this one exclusively. Thanks.

Comment: There are literally tons of autocompletion libraries on the web. Pick one that suit your case.

Comment: What have you actually tried?